# How can I update a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I'm trying to update a collection in MongoDB after doing some analysis using pandas, this is my code:

```
client=MongoClient()
db=client.database
cll=db.collection

cursor=cll.find()
df=pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

df['new_field'] = df['existing_field_A'].apply(lambda x: personalized_function(x))

cll.update_many(filter={}, update=df.to_dict('record'))
```

but the next error is raised:

```
    TypeError: update must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

Cause `df.to_dict('record')` is `<class 'list'>` so I changed my code to:

```
client=MongoClient()
db=client.database
cll=db.collection

cursor=cll.find()
df=pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

df['new_field'] = df['existing_field_A'].apply(lambda x: personalized_function(x))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        _id=row['_id']
        new_value=row['new_field']
        cll.update_one({'_id':_id}, {'$set':{'new_field':new_value}})
```

and it works fine, but I want to know if there is a better way to update my collection.

What can I do? Or how can I update the whole collection and not document by document?

Comment: Are you sure that `df.to_dict('record'))` is a `<class 'dict'>`? Print its type.

Comment: It is a list, but how can I update my collection?